# Does the position of the content in the source make a difference to SEO?

Tags: seo

Is a site penalised if the first propper (human readable) content comes after a lot of structural HTML code?  Is there any benefit to having the text content come earlier in the source (e.g. less HTML before it)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See number 8 on this page, http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors#ranking-factors for reference.

The short answer is you want your text content as close to the top as possible.  That being said it isn't a huge factor so don't get overly worried or do crazy things to optimize your content to the top of the code.  Google looks at a lot of other things that are much more important.